How to convert multiple lines to one line?
everyone:
i am a newer for ml.net, i have more than one lines to indicate an individual process, so i want to convert them to one line, so i can use regression or classification to deal with these data.For example i have 100 tables, each table include 20 lines, info in each table can describe a production procedure, so i should have 100 lines in a table finally, then i can start the normal ml process.


You don't need to convert anything to one line to use any kind of analysis. That's like saying you need to convert all values to a single one. What would make sense would be asking how to combine 100 dataframes into a single one. What you posted though looks like an Excel screenshot without headers, not code, dataframes or tables. Where does the data come from and how do you load it?

Perhaps you should check the multi-file example in the Load Data docs. You can load all files in a folder by passing "MyFolder/*" to LoadFromTextFiles
